# How to create a latlng object from user input using javascript

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to gmaps api and I'm having a problem creating a latlng from user inputs. I have a function that places the marker base on the input but it does not work. Entering literal numbers does work but not values from the texboxt. Can somebody help me out? TYIA!

here is my script for getting the lat and lng values:

```
var lat = parseFloat($('#lat').val());
      var lng = parseFloat($('#lng').val());
      var input = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

and then the function

```
      function placeMarker(location) {
  if ( marker ) {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  } else {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user intput after this script run ?

you should use `some` event like this

```
$('#lat, #lng').keyup(function () {
    var lat = parseFloat($('#lat').val());
    var lng = parseFloat($('#lng').val());
    placeMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
})
```

Comment: WOW! IT WORKS THANK YOU!